# I would like to open an image when a user clicks on a button in GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am trying to get an image to open within my frame once a button has been clicked, so far I have put the image in a JLabel within the button I want it to open to once clicked. But it shows up straight away. Any ideas on how to set it so that the image opens once the "scissors" button has been clicked?

```
    btnPlaySci = new JButton ("Scissors!");
    btnPlaySci.setBounds(180, 40, 110, 20);
    btnPlaySci.addActionListener(new PlaySciHandler());
    panel.add (btnPlaySci);
    btnPlaySci.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);

    //below is my image, and above is the button I want it to open to

    ImageIcon rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock.jpg");
    JLabel picture = new JLabel(rock1);
    picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400);
    panel.add(picture);
```

Edited code pasted in comment

```
class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String computerRand = sps.computerChoice(); 
            txtComputerRand.setText(computerRand); 
            String result = sps.play(Sps.SCISSORS); 
            txtResult.setText(result); 
            ImageIcon rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock.jpg"); 
            JLabel picture = new JLabel(rock1); 
            picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400); panel.add(picture); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code of PlaySciHandler class?

Comment: class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   String computerRand = sps.computerChoice();
   txtComputerRand.setText(computerRand);
   String result = sps.play(Sps.SCISSORS);
   txtResult.setText(result);
   ImageIcon rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock.jpg");
   JLabel picture = new JLabel(rock1);
   picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400);
   panel.add(picture);

  }
 }

Comment: hey sorry earlier my answer was incorrect but now it'll be able to do what you need.

Comment: remove the code from main class that set image to label. Click on button so that image will be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add the JLabel (containing image) to panel when button is clciked.

You will have to code the below class which will handle the event when user clicks button 'btnPlaySci'.

```
btnPlaySci.addActionListener(new PlaySciHandler(panel)); //replace your addActionListener line with this code.

import java.awt.event.*;
class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    JPanel panel;
    PlaySciHandler(JPanel p)
    {
         panel = p;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)   
    {
      ImageIcon rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock.jpg");
      JLabel picture = new JLabel(rock1);
      picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400);
      panel.add(picture);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried putting it into my action listener on top of what I already have but it does not come up?


 class PlaySciHandler implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   String computerRand = sps.computerChoice();
   txtComputerRand.setText(computerRand);
   String result = sps.play(Sps.SCISSORS);
   txtResult.setText(result);
   ImageIcon rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock.jpg");
   JLabel picture = new JLabel(rock1);
   picture.setBounds(60, 200, 400, 400);
   panel.add(picture);

  }
 }

Comment: I've updated the answer now it'll work. Just put this new class anywhere in existing source file or make new PlaySciHandler.java file

Comment: The `JLabel` should be added to the GUI before the user clicks anything.  When an image is selected, call `label.setIcon(Icon)`.  Don't use absolute bounds for components (they will typically be ignored) and make sure to `validate()`/`repaint()` the GUI after adding new components.  To the questioner - This answer may have solved the immediate problem, but doing it this way will add more problems down the track.